# Why is my while loop not getting broken when condition is met within try-except statement?

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-statements, try-except

I have some code which I would like to run into infinity unless a specific condition has been met. Within a try-except statement this condition is actually met and therefore I assumed the while loop would be broken, but apparently this is not the case. I am not sure why this does not break the while loop. Is try except overruling the while statement? Should I say after my try-except again something like `test=test.copy()` ? I've boiled it down to the code below for reproductive purposes.

```
test = None

while test==None:
    try:
        test="something changes in this try statement, should break while condition"
        print("even executed this line")
        #MY QUESTION IS WHY THE LOOP IS NOT BROKEN HERE

    except:
        print("this failed")

    print("try except passed, so here we do another thing to test to break the loop")
    test="after try-except statement changed test"

print(test)
```

prints:

```
#even executed this line
#try except passed, so here we do another thing to test to break the loop
#after try-except statement changed test
```

Comment: Seems you are trying to perform some sort of [shotgun debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_debugging) with your code, while I believe you should rather ensure you understand how `while` loop works, not to mention `try/catch` flow.

Comment: The output is as expected. Could you clarify what output you were expecting? Do you perhaps expect the condition for the while loop to be re-checked after every statement in the loops body, instead of once at the start of each iteration?

Comment: The loop seems to be exiting just fine.  It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to describe, and it sounds like you may just have some strange expectations of how code is executed.  When you step through this code in a debugger, which *specific operation* produces an unexpected result?  What was that result?  What result did you expect?  Why?

Comment: I expected the loop to be broken during the first try statement where test was changed from None to some string. I guess I need to further deepen my knowledge on while statements.

Comment: You seem to be expecting an implicit `break` immediately after setting `test` to a non-`None` value. That's not how loops work. The entire body of the loop is executed, *then* the condition is checked again.

Comment: @chepner, That clears up a lot, thanks :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of a `break` or `continue` statement, the body of the loop executes in its entirety before the condition is checked again. After setting `test = "something changes in this try statement, should break while condition"`, the condition `test == None` *will* evaluate to false, but not until the body of the loop completes. If you want to break *immediately, you have to test the condition explicitly:

```
test = None

while test is None:
    try:
        test = "something changes in this try statement, should break while condition"
        if test is not None:
            # This will exit the loop immediately.
            break
        print("even executed this line")

    except:
        print("this failed")

    print("try except passed, so here we do another thing to test to break the loop")
    test = "after try-except statement changed test"
```